# How can I get the innerHTML of a text that is overwritten with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, innerhtml

HTML:

```
<div class="col answer">
    some text
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".answer").text("Here we change the text" );
$(".answer").click(function(E) {
    console.log(E).html();
  });
```

console output : undefined

Comment: `console.log` returns `undefined`... did you mean `console.log($(this).html())`? E refers to the index

Comment: `console.log($(E.target).html())` would log the html.  or `console.log(E.target.innerHTML)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(this).html()` not `(E).html()`. Your code should look like this:

```
console.log($(this).html());
```

Demonstration:

```js
$(".answer").text("Here we change the text");
$(".answer").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="col answer">
  some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this was also posted in Javascript here's a vanilla option to do the same:

```html
<div class="col answer">
    some text
</div>

<script>

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");
    var y;
    for (y = 0; y < x.length; y++) {
      x[y].innerHTML = "Here we change the text";
    } 

    window.onload = function() {
        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
         var target = event.target;
         if(target.matches('.answer')){
           console.log(target.innerHTML);
          }
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `innerHTML` or `text`?? If you need text use `.text()` method.

```
$(".answer").text("Here we change the text" );
$(".answer").off().on('click',function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```